# Cordova: Can I generate my Android Application for a specific Androir Version?

Tags: cordova

I'm starting a new mobile project and I want to use Apache Cordova. I want my application to be used by people with older Android Device (Version >= 4.1). Can I configure Apache Cordova to generate my application for Android 4.1?

Regards,

Néstor

Answer (score 0):

You have this tags to configure the android versions

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="xx" />
<preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="xx" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="xx" />
```

- `minSdkVersion` is the lowest android version supported
- `maxSdkVersion` is the higher android version supported, it's not recommended to use it
- `targetSdkVersion` is the SDK used to build the app, should be the latest supported by cordova, right now it's 22.